Assign list of filenames to Pandas csv files
I have a list of dataframes that I am writing as individual csv's using a for loop, I wish to name each csv based on a list of names I have, currently stored as a list of string.
Dataframes are saved as df_list, this is the code I am using to write the csv files which currently just names them sequentially.
string_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for i, df in enumerate(df_list, 1):
    df.to_csv(f'file_{i}.csv')


This question is similar to: How do I iterate through two lists in parallel?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Instead of i, use string_list[i].  What is the difficulty?

You would need to index your list:
string_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.to_csv(f'file_{string_list[i]}.csv')

But better use zip, which is the pythonic way to iterate over several lists in parallel:
for s, df in zip(string_list, df_list):
    df.to_csv(f'{s}.csv')


It seems that your code is already quite close to what you want. The following would create the files first_name.csv, name_two.csv, and third_thing_here.csv out of df_list, assuming df_list is a list of three pandas dataframes.
name_list = ["first_name", "name_two", "third_thing_here"]

for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df.to_csv(f"{name_list[i]}.csv")

